# Subclassing NSMapTable

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, subclass

As there is no Collection in iOS for an Ordered NSMapTable (long story why I would need one in the first place :)) I tried to subclass it and implement one myself.

Unfortunately I'm facing some weird problems:

I can't add properties or even override the init method.

I always get prompted with an exeption:

> uncaught exception: `-[NSConcreteMapTable setKeyIndexArray:]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is my Code:

**OrderedMapTable.h**:

```
@interface OrderedMapTable : NSMapTable

-(id) objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

-(id) keyAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

**OrderedMapTable.m**:

```
@interface OrderedMapTable()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* keyIndexArray;

@end


@implementation OrderedMapTable


+(id)strongToStrongObjectsMapTable
{
    OrderedMapTable* orderedMapTable = [super strongToStrongObjectsMapTable];
    orderedMapTable.keyIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return orderedMapTable;
}

...
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you should not subclass Cocoa collection classes. (By the way, the exception message is a quite clear, meaningful English sentence. **Do read and understand it.**)

```
OrderedMapTable* orderedMapTable = [super strongToStrongObjectsMapTable];
```

This calls to `super` - that creates an instance of `NSMapTable`, and not an instance of your own subclass, which, of course, doesn't have a `keyIndexArray` property.

<s>A possible solution: allocate `self` and call a designated initializer on the created instance.</s>

```
OrderedMapTable *map = [[self alloc] initWithKeyOptions: NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions: NSMapTableStrongMemory capacity:0];
```

Disregard the above, as you mentioned too, it doesn't work, the `initWithKeyOptions:valueOptions:capacity:` method always creates an instance of a private subclass. There's no much you can do about it. Forget subclassing, basically.

Comment: Thanks but I know that the exepction meant. (It was just easier to copy the exception than to write that the property was not recognized..)

In my question I stated that overriding the init method does not work either. So your solution allocating self does **not** work..

Comment: `+(id)strongToStrongObjectsMapTable
{
    OrderedMapTable* orderedMapTable = [[OrderedMapTable alloc] initWithKeyOptions: NSMapTableStrongMemory valueOptions: NSMapTableStrongMemory capacity:0];
    orderedMapTable.keyIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return orderedMapTable;
}

-(id) initWithKeyOptions:(NSPointerFunctionsOptions)keyOptions valueOptions:(NSPointerFunctionsOptions)valueOptions capacity:(NSUInteger)initialCapacity
{
    NSLog(@"Not Called!");
}`

Neither the call with `self` nor with `OrderedMapTable` do work.

Why --> That's my question in the first place..

Comment: @dominik right, I just checked this too - in this case I have some bad news for you: you **can't** subclass `NSMapTable`. Why? [Because it's a class cluster.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html)

Comment: Well that's unfortunate.. I now ended up subclassing from NSObject and wrapping all the functionality around a property of kind NSMapTable. Thanks anyways for your help..

Comment: @dominik You're welcome. Yes, the approach you took is called "composition" and it is **the** solution recommended by Apple in these cases.

Comment: You often *can* subclass class clusters if you're careful—take a look at the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34) for details. However, you shouldn't do that if you're changing the behavior of the class, only if you're changing the way it stores its data. Here you're turning an unordered map into an ordered one, so subclassing `NSObject` is the right solution. Note that `NSOrderedSet` is not an `NSSet` subclass!

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon, that "subclass" is actually implementing the `NSMapTable` "interface", instead of extending the current available functionality, which I wish to do.

Comment: @FranklinYu Regardless, it says right in the docs: "NSMapTable is not suitable for subclassing."

Comment: @BrentRoyal-Gordon, yes, sadly. I can subclass the containers in Java and C++, so I thought I could do the same in Objective-C and Swift.